# changing opacity of html element while scrolling in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, opacity

i have a wordpress website [enter link description here](http://molugu.com/yantraev/about-company/#), i used a plugin to create the mobile menu, now the menu is sticky , i tried css position absolute to remove the stickiness but it doesnt work, so i am trying to change the opacity of the element to 0 so its not visible on scroll, i used the below code:

```html
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var offset = $(document).scrollTop()
        var opacity = 0;
        if (offset <= 0) {
            opacity = 0;
        } else if (offset > 0 & offset <= 200) {
            opacity = (offset - 1) / 200;
        }
        else {
            opacity = 1;
        }
        $('.mobmenu').css('opacity', opacity).html(opacity);
    });
```

but this doesnt work and i get the following error:

> TypeError: $ is not a function

can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing opacity while scrolling is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993238/changing-opacity-while-scrolling-is-not-working)

Comment: @JoshG i already have jquery cdn

Comment: @Priyajain i tried it, same error $ is not a function

Comment: I suspect your script is being executed before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: @JoshG jqury is coming by default, its a wordpress, i placed the code in footer, how do i make it execute after jquery load

Comment: @Crabzon Try replacing `$` with `jQuery`. Example: `jQuery(window).scroll(function () { ... });`.

Comment: @JoshG tried bro same  error,$ not a function

Comment: @JoshG this time the erroris coming whilei  scrollthe screen

Comment: If you replace `$` with `jQuery` everywhere then you shouldn't be getting an error about `$` not being a function. Something is still calling it somewhere on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to between `<head>` and `</head>`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```